# Why did Richard Garriott have to quarantine following his trip to the ISS?

Tags: iss, astronauts, quarantine

I was reading about [Richard Garriott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_Rasa_(video_game)#Closing) and the drama surrounding his departure from NCSoft, and I was surprised to learn that NCSoft forged his resignation letter while he was in quarantine following his trip to the International Space Station, which raised the question: Why did he have to quarantine?  I understand why the Apollo astronauts did; there could have been dangerous, novel pathogens on the Moon.  But nothing on the ISS is novel.

Comment: It's a guess and so not an answer, but perhaps quarentine after time on the ISS is to protect the astronaut from catching anything while in a post spaceflight/microgravity weakened state rather than protecting us earth dwellers from anything they might have picked up?

Comment: Can you provide evidence that he, or anyone, was quarantined upon return from ISS?  I know most astronauts stayed in "sick bay" for a while to undergo testing and to re-learn how to function in 1-g environment, but can't find any mention of a true pathogen-style quarantine.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I can't.  I just read the wikipedia article and watched a video in part about NCSoft that had even less info about Garriott's space flight.  It's quite hard to research actually.  Google sees the word "Quarantine" and thinks I want to read about the coronavirus.  If he wasn't actually in quarantine, that could be an answer itself.